# FLutter : Read frames fom video, process it, put it to output video

Tags: flutter, ffmpeg

I have video record and I need to process frames of this video, and for each frame/image write random integer on top left or right of image ( the random integer is only example I will replace this random int by my logic )

something like :

```
// 1. extract list of frames from video
// 2. process images/frames and add random integer in top left or right of image
// 3. Write output Video with new Frames contain the random integer
```

can someone help to have code example to resolve this by using [ffmpeg](https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter) package or any other package ?

Thanks